# How to get Colab to recognize the changes I've made to a file?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am having an issue with Colab's native text editor where I click on a file given in an error message, edit it, and run the cell, but I still receive the same error. I thought it might be a problem with the virtual environment, so I installed everything locally and encountered the same problem. Even if I delete all of the contents from the file, I still receive the same error. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the runtime? Go to Runtime menu > Restart Runtime